# DST changes caused an java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, simpledateformat, dst, datetime-parsing

Following is the code snippet which is throwing an exception:

```
SimpleDateformat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
Date date = dateFormatter.parse("201710010200");
```

The code above threw exception for all the dates after 2:00 A.M. It ran well till 01:30 A.M.

DayLight saving time was configured (I'm using `Australia/Sydney` timezone).

After that, I could see logs of 3:00 A.M.
Time between 2:00 A.M. and 3:00 A.M. is not logged too.

Log:

> 01 Oct 03:02:01 ERROR : Unparseable date: "201710010200"
>
> > Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "201710010200"
> >         at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)

What could be the fix of the problem of the date string `"201710010200"` not getting parsed, with the right date format specified?

Comment: Well what time zone are you in? If it's one where 2am on October 1st was skipped, that makes sense - that local time didn't exist.

Comment: (If these were meant to be timestamps, they should be logged in UTC and then parsed in UTC...)

Comment: no there are dates.. its of Sydney(Australia)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "no there are dates" but as I predicted, the Sydney time zone did indeed go forward at 2am on October 1st: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/australia/sydney. So basically, if you looked at a correct clock in Sydney, you would never see 2am or 2:30am for example. The clock would go 1:58, 1:59, 3:00.

Comment: they are date and time values according to format "yyyyMMddHHmm"

Comment: `201710010200` might be a valid date/time for **most** part of the world, but not in `Australia/Sydney` timezone, due to Daylight Saving Time. When clock reaches 2 AM, it jumps forward directly to 3 AM (actually, it jumps from 1:59 AM to 3 AM, so all the local times between 2 AM and 2:59 AM don't exist in this timezone, at that day). @JonSkeet answer explains that in detail, what else you don't understand?

Comment: Maybe [this code](https://ideone.com/E2t3mA) can help you to understand better.

Comment: Actually when i am trying to reproduce this issue with jdk1.7 version in India setting time zone to Australia through Java. Its not getting reproduced, its giving 3:30A.M. for 2:30 A.M successfully.

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by your comment, but my guess is that you were looking at a fall-back transition instead of a spring-forward transition - they're very different situations. (In a fall-back transition, any given local time can be represented by two different instants, so `parse` returns one of those - it will still format back to the same string. In a spring-forward transition, there *is* no instant that will format back to the original string.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to parse a date/time that didn't occur.

We now know that this was in the Sydney time zone. At 2am on October 1st 2017 in Sydney, the clocks went forward to 3am. If you were looking at a clock every minute you'd see:

- 01:58
- 01:59
- 03:00
- 03:01

So any date/time between 2am (inclusive) and 3am (exclusive) simply didn't occur in that time zone. We don't know what produced the values you're trying to parse, but:

- If they're timestamps, it would almost certainly be better to both format and parse in UTC. Keep an offset from UTC and potentially a time zone ID if the time zone in which they were produced is important for future analysis.
- If they're date/time values which aren't linked to any particular time zone, don't parse them as if they were *in* a time zone. Ideally, use Java 8's `java.time` package and parse them as `LocalDateTime` values

Comment: they are date and time values according to format "yyyyMMddHHmm"

Comment: @RaghavAgarwal: But it represents a date/time value that simply didn't occur in the time zone you're parsing it in. There is no `Date` value it could return that, when formatted back using the same `SimpleDateFormat`, would give the same string.

Comment: @RaghavAgarwal: To put it another way: what would you *expect* it to return? Bear in mind that [a `Date` value represents an instant in time](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) - which instant are you expecting it to return?

Comment: Date date = dateFormatter.parse("201710010200");

Comment: @RaghavAgarwal: That doesn't answer my question at all. That doesn't say what instant the value is meant to represent - it's just repeating the code in the question.

Comment: I want to get number of milliseconds represented by this Date object

Comment: @RaghavAgarwal: It's not clear to me that you've read *anything* I've written. What do you expect that number of milliseconds to be? That would indicate an instant in time. **There is no instant in time which had a local time of 2am on October 1st 2017 in Sydney.**

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse(                               // Parse a string lacking any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC into a `LocalDateTime` object.
    "201710010200" ,                               // Parse string in “basic” ISO 8601 format.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmm" )  // Define a formatting pattern to match the input. If you used expanded ISO 8601 format instead of “basic” you would not need to bother with this step.
).atZone(                                          // Place the inexact unzoned value (`LocalDateTime` object) into the context of a time zone. Produces a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    ZoneId.of( "Australia/Sydney" )
).toString()                                       // Generate a string in standard expanded ISO 8601 format. This class extends the standard to wisely append the name of the zone in square brackets.
```

> 2017-10-01T03:00+11:00[Australia/Sydney]

If that time-of-day on that date in than zone is invalid, `ZonedDateTime` class adjusts.

If you fear faulty input, trap for [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).

## Details

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46581667/642706) is correct. Per his comment: *There is no instant in time which had a local time of 2am on October 1st 2017 in Sydney.*

## java.time

The modern solution is the *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

### Parsing

Define a formatting pattern to match your input.

```
String input = "201710010200" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmm" ) ;
```

### `LocalDateTime`

Your input lacks an indicator of offset-from-UTC or time zone. So parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2017-10-01T02:00

Without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, this value has no real meaning. It does *not* represent a moment, a point on the timeline. It is only a vague idea about possible moments over a range of about 26-27 hours.

To determine a moment, we need to place this value within the context of a time zone or offset.

You claim to know that value was intended to represent a moment in `Australia/Sydney` time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Australia/Sydney" ) ;
```

> 2017-10-01T03:00+11:00[Australia/Sydney]

The result is *3 AM*. The [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) used by the people of that region changed on that date at that time, a cut-over in [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) silliness. When the clock in that part of Australia was about to strike 2 AM, the clock jumped to 3 AM. The 2 AM hour never existed in that land. The [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class has a policy for automatically adjusting such invalid moment. Be sure to read the doc to see if you understand [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)and agree with its algorithm.

Because this wall-clock time never existed, I suspect you are incorrect about that log data representing a moment in the zone of `Australia/Sydney`.

## UTC

The bigger solution here is to learn to think, work, log, and exchange data all in UTC. Consider UTC to be the *One True Time*, and all other zones are but a mere variation of that theme. Forget about your own parochial time zone while at work programming/administrating.

In *java.time*, the basic class for UTC values is `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

This class can capture the current moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

## ISO 8601

The `Instant` class also can parse/generate strings in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = Instant.now().toString() ;
```

> "2018-01-23T12:34:56.734591Z"

The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means UTC. This is the crux of your original problem: **You stored date-time values without such an indicator of zone/offset.**

Parsing:

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-01-23T12:34:56.734591Z" )
```

I strongly recommending using the ISO 8601 formats for all such storage/exchange of textual date-time values. Be sure to:

- *include offset/zone* when storing/exchanging moments, precise points on the timeline.
- *Use expanded formats*, rather than these “basic” formats that minimize the use of delimiters. These are hard to read by humans, less obvious as to the type of information, and are not used by default in *java.time*. The *java.time* classes use the expanded formats by default.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I think we can write a book about this; an answer cannot extend such.